# Issue with Textarea Content Overflowing under ActionBar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

On our webpage, we have a container with a structure similar to the one outlined below:

```
<div>
  <div class="Header"></div>
  <div class="Contents">This has the textarea and it grows vertically and has no specific height set and cannot have a fixed height</div>
  <div class="ActionBar">This is fixed at bottom 0</div>
</div>
```

The contents of the .Contents div include a textarea that dynamically grows vertically as users input content. However, we've observed that when the content extends beyond the visible area of the .Contents div, it goes below the fixed-position .ActionBar. This results in the newly entered text being hidden behind the ActionBar until the user manually scrolls up to reveal it.

We want the new data to be visible above the toolbar.

Comment: Please read your post before asking!, don't repeat yourself and use (I,the) instead of (we,our) to increase readibility.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative; bottom:0` to fix the actionBar at the bottom

```
  <style>
    .container {
      overflow: auto; 
    }

    .header {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .contents {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .actionBar {
      background-color: lightcoral;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

Here is the html [code](https://onecompiler.com/html/3zv49xjpq) to play around.

Comment: Thanks Anshu, But after adding position: relative in actionBar, the action bar itself goes to the end of contents, Due to this incase of large content actionBar goes out of screen, We want that action bar to be fixed in the bottom and visible always even if there is large data in contents.

Comment: @Sagar You want action bar to be fixed and you want the new data to be visible above the toolbar. Doesn't both contradict? What do you mean by 'visible above the toolbar'.

Comment: Likely means a higher z-index.